# Get a file from javascript to java using load()

Tags: javascript, java, file, upload

i'm a beginner and i want to hand an input (type=file) from a form to be read in javascript then to java.

i've already got the fileupload jars and the dependencies set. It works with the form action from jsp to java, but i need to do it differently. I dont know how to put it in the load() function in javascript, and then read it in java.

**EDIT :** i think i can't do it within the load which takes only some string values. but i need like to load the next page into a div, and also send the file got from the form from javascript to java

```
<form role="form" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label pull-left">File</label>
            <div class="col-sm-5">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file"
                    accept=".xlsx,.xls" class="form-control" required/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 control-label pull-right">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="Validatesubmitfile()">Enregistrer</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</form>
```

```
function Validatesubmitfile() {

    var pageHTMUpdate = 'URL1';
    // $('#modifierRow').attr('page', pageHTM);

    $("#etatChoisiIAM3")
    .load(
            pageHTMUpdate,
            { 

    }, function(response, status, xhr) {


    });

}
```

```
    @RequestMapping(value ="URL1", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String uploaderfct(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String message = "";
        System.out.println("Test");
return "TheFIRSTHTMLPAGEPATH";
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean load function? What does load have to do with uploading a file? You should be making a post/put request.

Comment: the load() in the javascript : in load i can normally get vars from that javascript to the java. example

Comment: Do you mean `$("#etatChoisiIAM3").load($("file").val())`

Comment: yeah actually etatChoisiIAM3 is just a div's id,

Comment: and yeah i want to do that : will that work ? can i get the file from java like that ?

Comment: i dont know if it will work at all i thought that was for the "values", there i need the "file"

Comment: problem is load is a GET request, use a post/put and you can easily recreate what load does in the success method.

Comment: Thanks for the help i'm gonna try searching that hoping it will do everything i need